# How to get values from a list in angular or how to autoFill reactive angular Form?

Tags: angular

`This is a very small problem to be asked but I don't get any solution.
I have created a reactive form for update API. and I am fetching a object using service of the student details which I want to update.
But  do not know how to autofill this reactive form with the data i get.

This is the data that I have fetched from other component.

```
studentData = { 
DOB: "1996-09-18"
address: "Kurushetra"
email: "kshama@gmail.com"
mobile: 5465824978
name: "Kshama sharma"
rollNo: 14
tAttendance: 0
}
```

MY HTML-

```
<header>
    <div class="logo">
      <img src="../../assets/logo.png" alt="">
    </div> 
    <div class="logout"><button>LogOut</button></div>   
</header>
<section class="main">
    <div class="main-heading">
        Update Student
    </div>
    <div class="wrapper-form">
        <form action="#" [formGroup]="updateStudentForm">
            {{studentData | json}}
            <div class="row" id="id">
                <label for="rollNo">RollNo</label><br>
                <input formControlName="rollNo" type="number" placeholder="RollNo">
                <small *ngIf="f.rollNo.invalid && f.rollNo.touched" class = "text-danger"><br> RollNo is required</small>
            </div>
            <div class="flex">
                <div class="row ">
                    <label for="name">Name</label><br>`your text`
                    <input formControlName="name" type="text" placeholder="Name">
                    <small *ngIf="f.name.invalid && f.name.touched" class = "text-danger"><br>Name is required</small>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <label for="DOB">DOB</label><br>
                    <input formControlName="DOB" type="date">
                    <small *ngIf="f.DOB.invalid && f.DOB.touched" class = "text-danger"><br>Date-of-Birth is required</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="email">Email</label><br>
                <input formControlName="email" type="email" placeholder="Email">
                <div *ngIf = "f.email.invalid && f.email.touched">
                    <small *ngIf="f.email.errors?.required" class="text-danger">Email is required</small>
                    <small *ngIf="f.email.errors?.email" class="text-danger">Email is invalid</small>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="address">Address</label><br>
                <input formControlName="address" type="text" placeholder="Address">
                <small *ngIf="f.address.invalid && f.address.touched" class = "text-danger"><br>Address is required</small>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <label for="tAttendance">Total Attendance</label>
                <input formControlName="tAttendance" type="number" placeholder="Total Attendance">
            </div>
            <div class="row" id="add-btn">
                <button  class="btn">Add</button>
                <button class="btn">Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
```

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminHomeService } from '../admin-home.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-update-student',
  templateUrl: './update-student.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./update-student.component.css']
})
export class UpdateStudentComponent implements OnInit {

  
  studentData:any[]

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder, private route : Router, private adminHomeService : AdminHomeService) {
    console.log(this.updateStudentForm.value);
   }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.studentData = this.adminHomeService.student;
    console.log(this.studentData);
  }
  get f()
  {
    return this.updateStudentForm.controls;
  }
  get rollNo(){
    return this.updateStudentForm.get('rollno');
  }
  get name(){
    return this.updateStudentForm.get('name');
  }
  get DOB(){
    return this.updateStudentForm.get('DOB');
  }
  get address(){
    return this.updateStudentForm.get('address');
  }
  get email(){
    return this.updateStudentForm.get('email');
  }

  updateStudentForm = this.fb.group({
    rollNo : ['', Validators.required],
    name : ['', Validators.required],
    DOB : ['', Validators.required],
    mobile: ['', Validators.required],  
    address : ['', Validators.required],
    email : ['', [Validators.required, Validators.email]],
    tAttendance: ['', Validators.required]
});
  cancelbtn(){
    this.route.navigateByUrl('student-details')
  }
}
```

MY component.ts

I have tried all ways to fetch values from studentData like-
studentData.value.rollNo, studentData.rollNo, studentData.get("rollNo"), but none of these support to fetch values from studentData.
How should I autofill the form, or fetch the values from the data I get.`

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#replacing-a-form-control-value

This should give you an idea how to solve your issue

```
updaterollNo() {
  this.rollNo.setValue(1);
}
```